# How to print class variables in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, random

So I am very new to coding and started with python, I am trying to build a class in a program that puts together a DnD party by randomising their attributes. So far I can get the program to initialise instances of the party members and just give the user a prompt on how many of the hero's to choose from they would like in their party. My issue is that after setting the lists up and getting everything in place. I am unable to print any of the attributes of the individual heros. Regardless of whether I am calling them from within the lists or if I am directly trying to print them. I have tried using `__str__` to create strings of the attributes but I am clearly missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random


class Party:

    def __init__(self, name="", race="", alignment="", class_=""):

        self.name = name
        while name == "":
            name = random.choice(names)
            # print(name)
        self.race = race
        while race == "":
            race = random.choice(races)
            # print(race)
        self.alignment = alignment
        while alignment == "":
            alignment = random.choice(alignments)
            # print(alignment)
        self.class_ = class_
        while class_ == "":
            class_ = random.choice(classes)
            # print(class_)
    def character_stats(self):
        return "{} - {} - {} - {}".format(self.name, self.race, self.class_, self.alignment)
```

Each attribute pulls a random value from a list. My format statement is the latest attempt to get the values of the attributes to print rather than the object/attributes instead.
I apologise if any of the terminology is wrong, very very new to this

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful. What *is* happening when you try and print them out? Can we see the code in which you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning anything else but the input, (in this case being an empty string  `""` to the attribuytes. In your minimal example you have this constructor:

```py
class Party:
    def __init__(self, name=""):
         self.name = name
         while name == "":
             name = random.choice(names)
```

After you randomly assign a new name from `names`, you should assign it to `self`, otherwise the local variable just goes out of scope when the `__init__` method finishes. This code snippet should work:

```py
class Party:
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        while name == "":
            name = random.choice(names)
        # Now we assign the local variable as 
        # an attribute
        self.name = name
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, this fix worked. Everything prints perfectly